# Live news feed for iPad?

Tags: ipados, rss

I have been leaving my iPad plugged into my dock and just keeping the Remote app running to display the album art.

Which leaves me wondering, is there some sort of 'live news feed' app that I can get for my iPad just to display my rss feeds in a glanceable manner which will automatically update my rss feed?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of to do this is to use Tweetdeck.  Tweetdeck scrolls tweets as they come in.

1. Create a new twitter account eg joshhnews
2. Add your RSS feeds to this [TwitterFeed](http://twitterfeed.com/) service (free), and link it to the new twitter account
3. In TweetDeck follow this new Twitter account.

You will then see the news stream through live with clickable links to the articles etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Amazingly, this seems to be the only way to do this right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a twitter app called Trickle for iPad/iPhone that automatically scrolls through single tweets from accounts you follow on twitter in large text on the screen. You can configure the refresh speed between 1 to 60 minutes as well as how long each tweet is displayed on the screen. Not one I know of that will do this for RSS feeds directly but twitter is a great service for at a glance news. The Trickle app costs 99 cents on the AppStore and is universal

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you happen to aggregate your feeds in Google Reader, it looks like [GoReader](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goreader-for-iphone-ipad-rss/id393147268) for the iPad ($5) might work well for you.</strike>

EDIT: As RobZolkos pointed out, GoReader only syncs automatically on startup.  After that, you have to manually tap the refresh button to fetch new articles.  Apparently, all current iOS feed readers work this way.  I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the SDK or if an auto-refresh feature has just not occurred to any of the developers.

Comment: I don't think this is a "hands free" solution , in that you still need to manually sync the rss feeds.  They won't stream into the app in real time.

Comment: @RobZolkos You're absolutely right -- and that's absurd.