# Live data app for iPad

Tags: ipad, ipados

Last article on this I found is from 12 years ago ([Live news feed for iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13133/live-news-feed-for-ipad)) so hoping there's new information.

I'd like to leave my iPad open during the day and get a live screen of news, weather, etc. There are two issues

1. **Diversity of news sources and multiple items displayed** - Apple News is OK but I'd like something customizable with RSS feeds, etc. MSN is kind of a chumbucket of salacious pictures and silly links.  Google News is OK but has only a single story in the main panel.
2. **Display constantly** - I can maintain constant display by turning off ipad auto-lock, but I'd rather have something that displays constantly and then asks for passcode when someone hits the home button or interacts with the device.

Tweetdeck (2011 answer) is, well...let's just say it's not an option for reasons. Plus I'd like a more diverse set of news, something like Upstract but customizable.

Comment: Please don‘t reask questions just because they are old. Also, this depends heavily on location and areas of interest.

Comment: Answer (tweetdeck) from 2011 is no longer valid so it seems appropriate to ask for an answer that's less than 11 years old. And I do not see any other answers other than that answer that is no longer relevant.

Comment: Question closed without explanation of how it should be re-worded, so off to Reddit.

Comment: See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for how to ask for software recommendations.